# Incrementing a cart value in ModalBottom sheet in flutter

Tags: flutter

After incrementing integer value on modal bottom sheet in flutter,it is updating only after closing and again opening ModalBottom sheet.
as I am trying to compare qty with it so that we can compare if qty is there or not.

- StatefulBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext
  context,
  StateSetter
  setState) =>
  new GestureDetector(
  onTap: () {
  setState(() {
  value++;
  });
  },
  child: new Text(
  "+",
  style: TextStyle(
  color: Colors
  .red),
  ),
  ))

I want to increment cart value which is 1 and by tapping on '+'which is an icon,
I want to incremant that 1 value on every tap on bottom sheet but what i am getting is,after tapping on '+' Incrementation of value is showing only after
closing of bottom sheet and then reopen it after clicking on a product.

Comment: please add more info then we can help you

Comment: Please add your code in the question so that we will be able to help you.

Comment: Editted it.Kindly response

Answer (score 0):

wrap your value text  with `StatefulBuilder()`  and you can change the states for more info

https://medium.com/flutterdevs/can-stateful-builder-step-into-shoes-of-stateful-widget-81af58824ed0

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.but i am getting error,using this,StatefulBuilder( builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) => new GestureDetector( onTap: () { setState(() { value++; }); }, child: new Text( "+", style: TextStyle( color: Colors .red), ), ))

Comment: before using it,changes were showing but after closing modal bottom sheet and then after reopen it.

Comment: should we use Stream builder

Comment: no you can do this with Statefullbuilder let me check

Comment: Bro now it's working,i was missing with some text which was not in StatefulBuilder